# Creating html controls on the fly (reflection?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The first part of my web app was creating an interface where the user can create field names and the data type to associate with the field names.
Now I need to create the 2nd part which is pulling those field names from the database along with the data types associated with them and creating html controls on the fly using those fields names/data types. For example, if one of the field names is "birthdate" and the data type is "datetime", then my view should automatically create a html textbox with name attribute "birthdate". If a field name is "Active" and the data type is a boolean, the view should automatically create a checkbox with name attribute "Active". Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this in MVC? I'm assuming I need to use reflection and that when I have to post back to data, I will have to send back a json object.

Comment: You'll have to create your own ModelMetadataProvider and ModelValidatiorProvider. This might be useful: http://mgolchin.net/posts/21/dive-deep-into-mvc-modelmetadata-and-modelmetadataprovider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't create my own htmlhelpers, but I did something similar. I used string builder to dynamically create the html in the get method of my controller and then posted that to the view.

Comment: while this may have worked, it goes against good practices in mvc and OOP. Helpers would have been a better way and can equate to the same method of string aggregation to generate the field.

Comment: The reason I cannot use html helpers is because I am using abstract pattern. The dynamic html controls i need to create on the fly are based on templates. When a user chooses a value in a drop down list, that value gets passed to my controller via an ajax post back which in turn gets passed to my repository. That value then is used to grab the correct template from the repository. That template then is used to create my html controls in a string builder in my action result. That string then gets returned to the view as an MVC string which is used to create the controls.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mvc htmlhelpers. for example a flexible htmlhelper for dropdownlist that accept collection and other parameters. another htmlhelper to get collection and delivers listbox and .....
and in your view you can use of this htmlhelpers by their types.